# Pycharm not able to upgrade or install packages

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, package

I am new to pycharm and installed it just yesterday. After installing I wanted to create a virtual env. that I can use for all future projects. After creating this venv. I tried to install a few packages in it but I was unable to do so.

After that, I read on some of the other similar questins and tried the solutions mentioned in them like:

1. Changing the repository.
2. Made sure my interpreter and python versions are correct and I have selected correct interpreter for my project. ( I only have latest python version in my computer.)
3. Re installed pycharm.
4. Created new venv. and tried to use that..Still same problem.

I am getting an error as following image shows: [Error Message I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FX8P.jpg)

After gettign this error I tried running the command mentioned in it through pycharm terminal but that also didn't work. Following code shows all the error messages I got.

```
PS D:\AC\Python Projects\Project1> pip install numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ameyc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\ameyc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\AC\Python Projects\Project1\venv\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "D:\AC\Python Projects\Project1\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "D:\AC\Python Projects\Project1\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "D:\AC\Python Projects\Project1\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "D:\AC\Python Projects\Project1\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\cmdoptions.py", line 29, in <module>
    from pip._internal.models.target_python import TargetPython
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.models.target_python'
```

After this I also tried to upgrade pip (my python has the version 21.2.4) from pycharm terminal and got similar that is shown below:

```
PS D:\AC\Python Projects\Project1> pip install -U pip==21.2.4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ameyc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\ameyc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\AC\Python Projects\Project1\venv\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "D:\AC\Python Projects\Project1\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "D:\AC\Python Projects\Project1\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "D:\AC\Python Projects\Project1\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "D:\AC\Python Projects\Project1\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\cmdoptions.py", line 29, in <module>
    from pip._internal.models.target_python import TargetPython
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.models.target_python'
```

If anyone has any clue how can I install packages, please let me
know.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Please, add that output to your question.

Comment: And also please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have added the error message I got after running the command iin pycharm, please let me know if anything else is needed from my side.